# <object> tag doesn't refresh when its data attribute is changed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg

I have an `<object>` tag on a web page, whose `data` attribute is changed programmatically in JS (jQuery, specifically). The `data` tag always points to a SVG image.

In Firefox, when the `data` tag is changed, the new SVG loads and all the proper events fire. In Chrome, this doesn't occur until I click on the SVG canvas -- once that happens, the new SVG displays and its associated events all fire.

Why is this? How can I force Chrome to refresh the `<object>` when I change its `data` attribute?

Answer (score 12):

Well, I was *really* bored tonight and I wanted to do something that wasn't schoolwork, so I dug through a lot of specs and forums for you.

The [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.3.1) doesn't seem to have any mention of SVG, so there's a dead end. The [HTML5 Spec Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/object.html#object) tells us that we can use `data` to invoke plugins and load content. The [HTML5 Spec Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-object-element.html#the-object-element) *does* [mention](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/svg-0.html#svg) SVG, telling us that SVG falls under the category of [embedded content](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#embedded-content).

**Because the [Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-object-element.html#the-object-element) adds additional detail to the `<object>` element as defined in the [Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/object.html#object), we could say that the behavior of loading `<object>` elements is not an accepted standard.** (Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Anyway, in the `<object>` specification, aside from all the usual technical jargon about how the browser should interpret the object by MIME-type etc... We find the part that's relevant to this question:

> 4.6: If the load **failed** (e.g. there was an HTTP 404 error, there was a DNS error), fire a **simple event** named **error** at the element, then jump to the last step in the overall set of steps (fallback).
>
> ...
>
> 10.: Once the resource is completely **loaded**, queue a task to fire a **simple event** named **load** at the element.

(*[Simple events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) merely mean that the events do not bubble (so we can't listen for it in any parent elements) and are not cancelable, and use the `Event` interface*)

So, looking at this, I figured that if I select the `<object>` element off the DOM, it should have an `onload` and `onerror` event, if not `object.addEventListener`.  If you look at the Mozilla Developer Network docs for [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute) and [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/object), much of the JavaScript documentation is incomplete.  Bummer.

Just goofing around with JSFiddle and the Chrome Dev Tools and Firefox Web Console, I found that they both supported `onload` and `onerror`, or so I thought.

## Results of testing

#### Google Chrome (18.0.1025.165) and Firefox (12.0)

**Supports**:

- `addEventListener('load', function(){})`
- `obj.onload = function(){};`

**Does not support (*events don't seem to fire*)**:

- `addEventListener('error', function(){})`
- `obj.onerror = function(){}`

As you can see from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFdsY/33/), in Chrome using the `load` event causes infinite loops.  It is not supposed to do this (according to the [editor's draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-object-element.html#the-object-element)):

> The above algorithm is independent of CSS properties (including 'display', 'overflow', and 'visibility'). For example, it runs even if the element is hidden with a 'display:none' CSS style, and does not run again if the element's visibility changes.

It looks like somebody [already filed a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123536), so if you would go and confirm the bug it would help the Chrome Developers Team.

## TL;DR

The behavior for loading objects is not an accepted standard yet, but you can go verify a [bug in the Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123536).  You could try doing as @Hello71 suggested and try removing the element from the DOM and re-adding it, but [I couldn't get it to work](http://jsfiddle.net/mFdsY/37/).

Comment: Just wanted to comment and say thank you :-) I have a few alternatives in mind that I will try next I am able.

Comment: This appear to be fixed in a patch from May 2017, but as of writing (December 2017) nothing has happened. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445557

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I got exactly the same issue. Have a look at the http://jsfiddle.net/unesJ/, I solved it with the following code:

The html:

```
<object id="graph" data="image1.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

The javascript:

```
var new_url = 'image2.svg';
$('#graph').attr('data', new_url);
$('#graph').load(new_url);
```

It work for me on

- Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m
- Firefox 17.0.1

Comment: This didn't work for me and I think its because it's actually placing the contents of URL within the element rather than setting the data attribute to the url.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried quite a few things. Unfortunately I've had to resort to doing the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').trigger('click');
}, 40);
```

No, I don't really have a better solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Hackish, but sometimes that's the best solution...

Comment: Actually I don't know that this even worked now lol. Such a PITA. I've had spotty results with any solution I try.