# Reloading Content of Object With New PDF file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, activex

I need to refresh the content of the object element after updating its file path like below.

```
<input type="file" onchange="$('#oPdf').attr('data',this.value')" />
<object id="oPdf" data='[path]' type="application/pdf" width="500px" height="100%"></object>
```

The value is set, but it doesn't seem to be updated using javascript.

I've managed to do it inside iframe, but I don't won't to use an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question has been answered here: [<object> tag doesn't refresh when its data attribute is changed in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366867/object-tag-doesnt-refresh-when-its-data-attribute-is-changed-in-chrome)

You may have some problems with it as  isn't a standard yet.

Good luck ;)