# how to refresh object tag in aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web

I am embedding the plugin in aspx page and in the java script based on certain condtion,I need to reload the object tag.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assets"]%>js/Util.js"
 <object name="MyPlugin" id="Myplugin" width="0" height="0" type="application/x-Myplugin">            
</object>
```

**Edited:**
I wanted to do something like this [Reloading a loaded plugin](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Deploying+and+updating+your+plugin).

Please help me reloading the plugin in java script.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Lloyd:I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Refer these Link it may be use full to you

[object tag doesn't refresh when its data attribute is changed in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366867/object-tag-doesnt-refresh-when-its-data-attribute-is-changed-in-chrome)

[Changing data content on an Object Tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676705/changing-data-content-on-an-object-tag-in-html)

[Refresh / Reload Page at specific intervals](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Reload-Refresh-and-Redirect-Pages-using-Meta-Tags-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

You can Modify these codes to your requirement.

Comment: I need to just reload the object tag in aspx page.I dont need to change data content here.